# Transforming HSTORE array values to a column in JSONB

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb, hstore

I am trying to transform my data stored in HSTORE column ('data') of Postgres.

My row values have key "entity" and value is in the array.

```
"entity"=>"[{'id': .............}]
```

I used the following code:

```
Alter TABLE my_table 
   ALTER COLUMN h_store_column TYPE jsonb 
   USING hstore_to_jsonb_loose(data -> 'entity');
```

which resulted in value as output in a new column as below:

```
"[{'id': .............}]"
```

but, with quotes `""`. This made it scalar in JSONB type column and doesn't let me run the query.

How can I change the value of every row in a new column named 'entity' with JSONB, without quotes?

```
[{'id': .............}]
```

SAMPLE CODE TO GENERATE SIMILAR DATA:

```
"key" => "[json_text_array]"
```

stored in `hstore` data type column.

When changed to JSON B type, I get `{'key':'[array]'}`, whereas I am after `{'key': [array]}` - No quotes. I tried loose functions in postgres, no help.

Comment: Please add some reproducible sample data

Comment: Please show us something reproducible/accurate.  I get `ERROR:  function hstore_to_jsonb_loose(text) does not exist`

Comment: Hi, I just added more to description. @AkhileshMishra, here is a value of a row in hstore.

"entity" => "[{'id': '11954_179415600_2441_333_1',
 'vehicle': {'trip': {'tripId': '1182456',
   'routeId': '2441_333',
   'startDate': '20200822',
   'startTime': '22:14:00',
   'scheduleRelationship': 'SCHEDULED'},
  'vehicle': {'id': '11954_179415600_2441_333_1'},
  'position': {'speed': 0.0,
   'bearing': 297.0,
   'latitude': -33.876972,
   'longitude': 151.21237},
  'timestamp': '1598100524',
  'congestionLevel': 'RUNNING_SMOOTHLY',
  'occupancyStatus': 'MANY_SEATS_AVAILABLE'}}]"

Comment: `{'id': …}` is not valid JSON. `{"id": …}` would be. If your value looked like that, you could use `(data -> 'entity')::jsonb`. (Notice that `hstore_to_jsonb_loose` is absolutely unnecessary as `-> 'entity'` already accesses the string value in the hstore).

Comment: Please do not put additional information in comments (especially not "code" type things). **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 2):

As per your question what I understood, you have a column with type `hstore` having a key named `entity` and value as `JSON ARRAY`. Explanation of your problem and solution will be as:

1. Your `Alter` query mentioned in the question will through error because `hstore_to_jsonb_loose` function accepts `hstore` type value but you are passing `text`. So the correct statement for query should be.

```
    Alter TABLE my_table 
       ALTER COLUMN h_store_column TYPE jsonb 
       USING hstore_to_jsonb_loose(data) -> 'entity';
```

2. Above query will convert the `hstore` key-value into jsonb key value pair and update it into the column `h_store_column`.

So the function `hstore_to_jsonb_loose` will convert the data as  `{ "entity": "[{'id':..........}]" }` from which you are your extracting the `JSON` value of key `'entity'` which is `"[{'id':..........}]"`.

3. You want to store your value fetched from `hstore_to_jsonb_loose(data) -> 'entity'` as full `JSON ARRAY`. Your data stored as value in `hstore` type column seems like a `JSON` but its not a `JSON`. In `JSON`, keys and values (other than numeric and boolean) are surrounded by `"` but in your string it is surrounded by `'`. So it can not be stored as `JSON` in **JSONB** type column.
4. Considering that there is no other problem in the structure of values as JSON (other than `'`). We should replace the `'` with `"` and store the value as JSONB in the column. Try This query to do the same.

```
Alter TABLE test 
   ALTER COLUMN h_store_column TYPE jsonb 
   USING replace(hstore_to_jsonb_loose(data)->>'entity','''','"')::jsonb;
```

[DEMO1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b1aca3b75362cf27232aeef40c1f34d4)

Even `hstore_to_jsonb_loose` is not required in your case. You can write your `Alter` statement as below:

```
Alter TABLE test 
   ALTER COLUMN h_store_column TYPE jsonb 
   USING replace((data)->'entity','''','"')::jsonb;
```

[DEMO2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c2e6576440eac13c744d75a70357e590)